# Mercurial error when pulling or cloning over

Tags: iis-7, mercurial

We have a Mercurial clone hosted on IIS7. The clone has grown and now we are getting the following error when pulling or cloning from it over the web:

```
mpatch.mpatchError: patch cannot be decoded
```

However, when we host the clone through TortoiseHG's webserver everything works fine. Does anyone know what IIS settings to change to get past this?

(we have opened an issue on the Mercurial site, but that is going way too slow)

Comment: Have you run a `hg verify` on the repository on the server, just to make sure it isn't corrupted?

Comment: The repo is fine. When we use the tortoisehg webserver we have no problems.

Comment: tortoisehg serving it isn't enough to know it's fine.  Please confirm you've actually run `hg verify`.

Comment: I ran hg verify, the repo is fine. OUTPUT: 20402 files, 476 changesets, 41086 total revisions

Comment: Have you enabled any extensions in IIS, like url rewriting or similar?

Comment: When we ran it as a cgi site, yes, we had url rewriting activated. When we are running it as ISAPI, no. It gives the same problems with both those configurations. It really does seem if one of the changesets are too large and that IIS is maybe timing out.

Comment: Rather than cloning try doing `hg init` and then `pull -r X` for increasingly large values of X and see if you can make it work getting the data in smaller chunks -- or if you can identify a problem changeset.

Comment: And what do I do if I eventually identify the changeset? IIS is pissing me off. I'd rather switch to apache atm :(

Comment: It's happen to me too. But only if try access server from production server, that lies faar away from repository. It's seems to be some timeout issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We installed Apache Tomcat (took a day, go figure) and all is well. It seems that it's only IIS7 giving problems and that there maybe are some settings I am not aware of. So this is the solution for now. Would be awesome if someone could come up with the IIS solution and let me know.

Comment: Why did you use Tomcat and not just the Apache HTTP Server? I thought you use Tomcat for JAVA applications...